# Equivalent condition for continuity of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Let $g: [0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and let $f: [0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by 
\begin{equation}
f(t) = \inf \{ s \geq 0 \,|\, g(s) > t\}.
\end{equation}
Is it true that $f$ is continuous at $t$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $g$ is strictly monotone on $(t- \delta, t+ \delta)$, for some $\delta >0$?

If not, do you know any equivalent condition of continuity of $f$ at $t$ (in terms of properties of $g$)?

Comment: What is your definition of continuity? There are many.

Comment: Well, there are many, but they are all equivalent. There is one epsilon-delta characterisation, one with sequences and one with open sets.

Comment: OK. Can you clarify what you meant when you asked "do you know any equivalent condition of continuity of $f$ at $t$"

Comment: I mean, in terms of properties of $g$.

Comment: $g$ need not be strictly monotone even though it is continuous. Take the function $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$ and $f(x)=x^2sin(\frac{1}{x})$ if $x>0$. Then g is not monotone in any neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: This is an if and only if statement. So I am not assuming strict monotonicity of $g$.

Comment: "$g$ is strictly monotone on $(t-\delta, t+\delta)$" doesn't make sense. Did you mean $g^{-1}(t)$ instead of $t$? (whenever $t$ belongs to range of $g$.)

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think the claim is right. This is my counter-example. Would appreciate it if someone could verify it.

Define $g : [0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ by $g(t)= \sin 3 \pi t$. Now let $t =  \dfrac{1 }{2}$. Now, $$  f(\frac 1 2) = \inf \{s \ge 0 \ | \ \sin 3 \pi s \gt \frac 1 2  \}  = \frac 1 {18}$$

Now I believe $f$ is continuous at $ \dfrac 1 2 $ (which I think can be agreed with the continuity of the $\sin^{-1}$ function around $\dfrac 1 2$).  But, the function $g$ is not monotone on any neighbourhood around $\dfrac 1 2$ since $t = \dfrac 1 2$ is a minimum point of $g$.